# XML SSIS Returning no rows

Tags: xml, xsd, ssis

I have an SSIS package I created that is set up to pull in data from an XML file into 8 different SQL tables. It executes without an errors, but no data is passed to the SQL tables it's pointed to. The XML Source Editor would not generate and XSD file, so I used an online generator to create the XSD.

Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Do you see data in the source viewer?   When you execute it in BIDS do you see rows being passed through the data flow?

Comment: Show a sample of the XML and at least the "header" of the XSD you use.

Answer (score 1):

Most possible issue is that the namespace does not match with the namespace in the file.